# Render artifacts in Mac when using OutlinePass

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am trying to use an *OutlinePass* effect in my *react* application, but I am having a few issues:

- The whole scene is getting darker when the effect is
  added to my *EffectComposer*.
- Some artifacts appear in the render when using a Mac
  device on Chromium.

Both of the previous issues also appear when using other posprocessing tools, such as *UnrealBloomPass*.

Here are some pictures of the renders before and after adding the outline pass in Windows:

[image]

[image]

Here are some pictures of the renders before and after adding the outline pass in Mac (using Chrome):

[image]

[image]

As for the code, the following function handles most of the general rendering:

```
const initMap = () => {
        if (renderer==null) {

            container = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );
    
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            addPerspectiveCamera();

            //Composer and renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvasRef.current, antialias: true, precision: "highp"});
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
            renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding
            renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1
            renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
            renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap

            const size = renderer.getSize( new THREE.Vector2() );
            const _pixelRatio = renderer.getPixelRatio();
            const _width = size.width;
            const _height = size.height;

            var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( _width * _pixelRatio, _height * _pixelRatio, {
              minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
              magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
              format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
              encoding: THREE.sRGBEncoding
                 } );

            compose = new EffectComposer(renderer, renderTarget);
            renderPass = new RenderPass(scene, perspectiveCamera, pointLight, light);
       
            //Outline pass 
            outlinePass = new OutlinePass(new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight),scene,perspectiveCamera, pointLight, light);
            outlinePass.renderToScreen = true;
            outlinePass.selectedObjects = selectedObjects;
                
            //Add passes to composer
            compose.addPass(renderPass);
            compose.addPass(outlinePass);     //TODO - fix this in MAC (!!!!)
            
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            const interaction = new Interaction(renderer, scene, perspectiveCamera, pointLight, light);

            if (props.localMap) {
              addLocalMap();
            } 
            if (!props.localMap) {
              addWorldMap();
            }

        }

        //addOrbitControls();
        animate();
    }
```

Outline does work, as shown here (on Windows):

[image]